# How do you optimize creating and destroying DOM elements on every API call? Is there a better way of handling this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose, I'm creating a dropdown which populates the results based on the user's search term.
I have an input element and a ul:

```
<input id="search-input" type="text" value="" />
<ul id="dropdown-list">
 
</ul>
```

I use a for loop to iterate over the API response and create the respective number of "li" elements, and append them to ul.

```
let listContainer = document.getElementById("dropdown-list"); // ul
let inputElem = document.querySelectorAll(".search-input");

function removeItems() {
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-list-item");
  listItems.forEach(() => {
     listItems.remove();
  })
}

inputElem.addEventListener("onChange", (event)=> {
   removeItems();
   for(let i=0; i<api_response.length; i++) {
   let listItem = document.createElement("li");
   li.classList.add("dropdown-list-item");
   li.innerText = api_response[i];
   listContainer.appendChild(li);
  }
})
```

Please ignore the syntax, as it's a rough one.

But basically, the question I have is, re-creating and removing elements every time whenever there's a new API call seems really expensive. Is there a better way of doing this?
Could we for example, compare the current and previous elements length and just add new elements, and just replace the innerText for the existing elements, instead of completely destroying and re-creating the elements?

I wonder how do libraries like React do this?

EDIT: I know we use JSX in React to map over the elements and assign the keys to the elements. Also read about diffing algorithm. But just wondering how we would do in vanilla JS without all these optimizations? Re-creating and destroying DOM elements on each API call seems really expensive.

Comment: they use a virtual dom (https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html) and only render element that have changed in their model.

Comment: The JS way would be to create a [fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment), attach all the relevant nodes to that, and then pin that fragment to the DOM.

Comment: @JiaSH I am trying to understand how the vDOM does this. Are there any good resources that explain this in depth?

Comment: @Andy With fragment, do we avoid destroying the DOM elements and re-creating them?

Comment: react uses a data structure, likely a graph to keep a representation of the current page in memory. itll keep a graph of the current dom (aka virtualized DOM) and the previous DOM before any updates, then it will find the "difference" between the two. Then only trigger a renders (to the actual DOM) down the graph path to those diff'd components. Ji aSH left you a link for react internals. Look there for reliable info.

Comment: Thanks for answering @MattPengelly.

I read about the reconciliation algorithm that React uses, but your explanation makes it much more clear, visualizing it as a graph.

Comment: no problem, but defintely go to the source to learn the most, im just paraphrasing, I could even have made mistakes! So be wary :)

Answer (score 1):

The better way of doing this in react is actually making it in jsx. Its better always to avoid all "document.getElement..." in react because in this way you are working with actual DOM, so just do it in jsx and leave other for react.

I'll make a little example for you:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [dropDownItems, setDropDownItems] = setState([]) 

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <input id="search-input" type="text" value="" />
      <ul id="dropdown-list">
        {dropDownItems.map(item => (
           <div>{item.name}</div>
        ))}  
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

Thats not a full example but main thought. You make your request in input's onChange, after successful call you put response to dropDownItems, and it will be automatically rendered to your dropdown list. There is no need of searching for some elements in DOM by yourself.

I hope it helps, if not, ask questions and I'll try to answer them.

**UPDATE**

So for your situation I think that you may use Map, where key will be id of element or something like that.

Now you have all keys of your elements that currently exist in DOM. After this, you can go through your Map and check if key exists in your response from api, if not, you delete that element from DOM and key from map. And final step is you go through your response from api, and check if that element exists in your map. On final step you will have there only keys that exists in your map and response at the same time, so you skip elements if they exists in map and add to DOM new elements if not, also add this key to your map.

After that you will have updated DOM and a map that represents DOM.

Any operations with DOM are very heavy, so ability to check if element exists in DOM without touching DOM itself will save you a lot of time.

Actually that answer is not 100% correct, because in that case we will lose order of your elements in DOM and it will not represent your actual order of elements in array returned from api, but still it might be helpful.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for answering! My question was regarding the vanilla DOM. I think my question might have confused you.
I wanted to know how we'd do it without any libraries like React, and conversely, how do libraries like React handle this internally? The reason I'm asking is because I know how to do it in React, but I was asked to do this in vanilla JS in an interview, and I did come up with a solution, but it didn't seem like the optimal one, perf wise.

Comment: this doesnt involve react. OP only invoked react to support his question. this is not a valid answer to the question at hand

Comment: Oh, got it. I think it was a great interview, like "you have 10 minutes, implement react from scratch" :)

Comment: Thank you, @OlegBrazhnichenko.

Your answer makes a lot of sense. I'm just trying to visualize it now, and see how it could be implemented. Definitely would like to tackle this problem during my free time using your approach.

Comment: Glad that it helped :) 
If my answer helped you, I will appreciate some vote up on my answer :)

Comment: Done, I've upvoted it @OlegBrazhnichenko